# Most efficient algorithm for computing norm of the residual for the least squares problem in the rank deficient case

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, algorithms

I have a large $m\times n$ data matrix $A$, $m>n$, and response $m$-vector $b$.  I need to calculate $E = ||Ax-b||_2$ as quickly as possible, where $x$ is the least squares solution.  I don't need to actually know $x$.  The data matrix $A$ may not have full rank.  What is the fastest algorithm to calculate $E$ in this case?